# Python error: TypeError: ("<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas.Timedelta'> is not convertible to datetime")

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-datetime

I am calculating the difference between two times in minutes. I have a dataframe which has four columns:

df1:

```
 Notified Start Time', 'Notified End Time',  'Actual Int Start Time', 'Actual Int End Time'
0      3/01/2020 9:00   3/01/2020 19:00          3/01/2020 9:00              3/01/2020 14:00
1      4/01/2020 9:00   4/01/2020 17:00          5/01/2020 9:00              5/01/2020 20:00
2      6/01/2020 8:30   6/01/2020 20:00          7/01/2020 8:30              7/01/2020 19:00
3      8/01/2020 8:30   8/01/2020 12:00          9/01/2020 9:00              9/01/2020 18:00
```

The datatype of data frame is:

```
Notified Start Time                object
Notified End Time                  object
Actual Int Start Time              object
Actual Int End Time                object
```

I have defined a function that calculates the length of time between two dates in minutes.

```
def calc_timeDiff(start_date,end_date):
    fmt = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'

    end_date = pd.to_datetime(end_date,format=fmt)

    start_date = pd.to_datetime(start_date,format=fmt)            
    timediff = end_date - start_date

    timediff =pd.to_datetime(timediff)
    return (timediff.dt.hour * 60 + timediff.dt.minute + (timediff.dt.second/60)).astype(float)
```

The above function works fine when I create a new column in dataframe. For example,

```
df['ActualLength'] =  calc_timeDiff(df['Actual Int Start Time'],df['Actual Int End Time'])
df['NotifiedLength'] =  calc_timeDiff(df['Notified Start Time'],df['Notified End Time'])
```

The problem comes in when I tried to use the same function within other function that calculates some value.

```
def calc_value(func_df):
   if func_df['NotifiedLength'] < func_df['ActualLength']:
      if (func_df['Actual Int Start Time'] >= func_df['Notified Start Time']):
         fullValue = func_df['ActualLength'] - calc_timeDiff(func_df['Notified End Time'],func_df['Actual Int End Time'])
         return fullValue
```

I call the second function for creating another column in the dataframe:

```
df['ActualOutage'] = df.apply(calc_value,axis=1)
```

When I run the above code, it throws an error message:

```
 TypeError: ("<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas.Timedelta'> is not convertible to datetime", 'occurred at index 2')
```

which points to the 5th line (i.e. `timediff =pd.to_datetime(timediff)`) of the first function. I tried to troubleshoot the problem but failed. Could anyone guide me where am I making the mistake?

Comment: Comment that line out.

Comment: Sorry I didnt get it, what do you m ean by comment that line out.

Comment: You should not need to convert to a datetime object. `timediff` is/are timedelta object. Comment the line that causes the error ( put `#` in front of it). then see what happens. - https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timedeltas.html#attributes

Comment: I already tried that when I comment out the convert line, it throws an error of AttributeError: 'TimedeltaProperties' object has no attribute 'hour' (points to the last line of the first function)

Comment: Read through the documentation link I posted - total_minutes should be `timediff.dt.total_seconds() / 60`. - https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timedeltas.html#attributes

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/series.html#timedelta-methods

Comment: It throws AttributeError: ("'Timedelta' object has no attribute 'dt'", 'occurred at index 2') when I change to timediff.dt.total_seconds()/60.

Comment: The error message from the Exception in your question says it is a Timedelta.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your code on python 3.8 and pandas 1.1.0. I got the error `TypeError: dtype timedelta64[ns] cannot be converted to datetime64[ns]` right from the first function. I think the error is self-explanatory: you cannot convert a time difference to a timestamp by calling to_datetime() on it. A timedelta has no reference in time to be converted to a stamp. That being said I'm surprised you code doesn't throw an error in the first function.

Here is a possible solution that worked for me. Convert each column in the dataframe to a Timestamp.

```
df['Notified Start Time']=pd.to_datetime(df['Notified Start Time'])
df['Notified End Time']=pd.to_datetime(df['Notified End Time'])
df['Actual Int Start Time']=pd.to_datetime(df['Actual Int Start Time'])
df['Actual Int End Time']=pd.to_datetime(df['Actual Int End Time'])
```

Now if you run a `df.info(verbose=True)` on your dataframe you will see that everything has been converted to datetime64[ns]. Then you can start calculating timedeltas directly, for example:

```
df['ActualLength']=df['Actual Int End Time']-df['Actual Int Start Time']
df['ActualLength']
0   0 days 05:00:00
1   0 days 11:00:00
2   0 days 10:30:00
3   0 days 09:00:00
Name: ActualLength, dtype: timedelta64[ns]

df['NotifiedLength']=df['Notified End Time']-df['Notified Start Time']
df['NotifiedLength']
0   0 days 10:00:00
1   0 days 08:00:00
2   0 days 11:30:00
3   0 days 03:30:00
Name: NotifiedLength, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Or perform operations to calculate total time elapsed directly on the newly calculated column:

```
df.ActualLength.iloc[0].total_seconds()/60  
300.0
```

Or define a new column on which you can now perform subset operations as selection rules:

```
df['dL']=(df.ActualLength-df.NotifiedLength).dt.total_seconds()
df['dL']
0   -18000.0
1    10800.0
2    -3600.0
3    19800.0
Name: dL, dtype: float64
```

Final suggestion: if you already have `Timestamp` and `Timedelta` columns in your dataframe take advantage of built in Pandas functions such as `pd.date_range()`, `pd.timedelta_range()`, `pd.period_range()` rather than building your own. The built-in functions are quite robust against formatting issues.

I understand that all of this can be a bit confusing and it takes time to clear it up. But what has helped me is being consistent with the use of the tools that Pandas provides.

I sincerely hope the above helped.